# Is there any downscaled income data for representative concentrations pathways?

Tags: climate-change, geography, database

I know that downscaled income data existed for The Special Report on Emissions Scenarios (SRES) Scenarios for IPCC's climate change scenarios. (http://ciesin.columbia.edu/datasets/downscaled/)

For the successor of SRES scenarios, Representative concentration pathways (RCP), is there any downscaled dataset?